# CSS centered div isn't centered in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

My centered div box, that has an image in it and is centered with CSS, appears really off on Firefox! Somehow it's been offset down, if that makes sense?

It looks fine in both Safari and Chrome, and I'd really like to be able to get it right in FF as well.  Here is my CSS bit:

```css
body {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: ;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 5% 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
div#mainimg {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.centeredmainimg {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainimg">
  <img class="centeredmainimg" src="http://carriejade.com/images/name.png" />
</div>
```

My point was to have everything (my name image + the magenta line) to be centered no matter the screen resolution (and browser, but alas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code in firefox, and it worked perfectly (even in chrome):

```
position: fixed;
margin: auto;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, how can this code help in the give scenario.

Comment: All I did was set "bottom" to 0px; you had it set to 50%. Hence, bottom, left, right and top are all set to 0px, which basically centered a fixed div to the center of the page.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have the layout set up is kind of a hack so I had to end up correcting most of style2.css on your site. You can use css `display:flex`, `flex-flow: row;` and `justify-content` to achieve the same layout without custom positioning on every element. This fixes the centering issue you were having.

```
/* CSS Document */
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-size: 0;
}
body * {
    font-size: 12pt;
    line-height: 14pt;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #000;
}
div#topdiv {
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 24px;
    background:#fff45f;
    text-align:center;
    z-index: 2;
}
div#bottomdiv {
    height:30px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background:#ec008c;
    text-align:justify;
    z-index: 2;    
}
div#middlediv {
    line-height:10px;
    background:#ec008c;
}
div#mainimg {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:30px;
    top: 40px;
    left:0px;
    right: 0px;    
    z-index: 2;
}
.centeredmainimg {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time! What is the * for next to the second "body" bit?